# Access Datatable content in jQuery with dynamically created button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I'm new to jQuery. I need to access the datatable contents when I press the erase button. I tried lot of method but it returns undefined.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    loadData()
});

function loadData() {

    var table = $('#example').DataTable({

        "ajax" : {
            "method" : 'POST',
            "crossDomain" : true,
            "dataType" : 'json',
            "contentType" : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            "dataSrc" : "",
            "url" : "http://localhost:8081/Lakshmi_Service/admin/full"
        },

        "columns" : [ {
            "data" : "adminName"
        }, {
            "data" : "address"
        }, {
            "data" : "emailId"
        }, {
            "data" : "otp"
        }, {
            "data" : "expiryDate"
        }, {
            "data" : "mobileNo"
        }, {
            "targets" : -1,
            "data" : null,
            "defaultContent" : '<button>Erase</button>'
        } ],

        "iDisplayLength" : 5,
        "bAutoWidth" : true,
        "bSort" : false,
        "aLengthMenu" : [ [ 10, 25, 50, -1 ], [ 10, 25, 50, "All" ] ],
        "bDestroy" : true,
        "bFilter" : false,
        "bLengthChange" : false
    });

    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'button', function(event) {
        var aData = table.fnGetPosition(this);
        var oTableData = table.fnGetData(aData[0]);
        var ids = oTableData[aData].adminName;
        alert(ids);
    });
}
```

I need this `adminName` value when I click erase button to call another service. My page looks like:

[image]

My html page is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"
    src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"
    src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">

<title>Guru Statistics</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered"
        cellspacing="0" width="60%">
        <thead>
            <tr title="Name">
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>address</th>
                <th>mailId</th>
                <th>otp</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Mobile No</th>
                <th>Erase</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="home.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is add classes to your cells (adminName, address...) in the "columns" (I use aoColumns) dataTables object, and then use this piece of jQuery inside your `click` event

```
$(this).parents("tr").find(".adminName").text();
```

this way you should be able to get the value of the adminName of the row you clicked in

if you don't want to add classes (you should!) you could still get your data this way I guess :

```
$(this).parents("tr").find("td").first().text();
```

But I discourage you to do that, as if one day you decide to add a new column that's placed before adminName (say "Id" for exemple) your code will retrieve the `Id` and not the `adminName`, which will probably break your code.